# Group lists by number of X based on a condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a list like this

```
var items = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item { Image = "/path1", Title = "Title1" },
                new Item { Image = "", Title = "Title2" },                
                new Item { Image = "/path2", Title = "Title3" },
                new Item { Image = "/path3", Title = "Title4" },
                new Item { Image = "/path4", Title = "Title5" },
                new Item { Image = "", Title = "Title6" }
            };
```

Need to group items in a way that X number (for example 3) of items that have an image will be in the first group, then next X (3) items with no image, then next X items with image, then next X items with no image...

So for my example above the expected output would be

```
{ hasImage, [Item { Image = "/path1", Title = "Title1" }, Item { Image = "/path2", Title = "Title3" }, Item { Image = "/path3", Title = "Title4" }] },
{ !hasImage, [Item { Image = "", Title = "Title2" }, Item { Image = "", Title = "Title6" }] },
{ hasImage, [Item { Image = "/path4", Title = "Title5" }] }
```

Comment: I need groups of 3 (in the example code) of each type. 3 WITH image, 3 WITH NO image, 3 WITH image, 3 WITH NO image, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the IComparable interface, in combination with array.sort().
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-7.0

The IComparable interface allows you to give every value a number, and then sort an array based on the number given for each value. I hope this helps, if you have more questions don’t hesitate to ask me!

Edit: You probably want to look at [GFG’s guide to IComparer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-sort-list-in-c-sharp-set-1/).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide an example code?

Comment: @Vardan Unfortunately, I am not at my computer right now. However, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-sort-list-in-c-sharp-set-1/ Might provide a good answer for you. I will edit my answer.